# Use parameter passed to form constructor in CreateParams in WinForms.NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, constructor, createparams

I have a custom form defined like this:

```cs
internal class DropDownForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public DropDownForm(bool needShadow)
    { ... }
}
```

I need to enable form shadow depending on the needShadow parameter passed to the form constructor in the overridden CreateParams member - something like this:

```cs
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

        if (needShadow)
            cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;

        return cp;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't access the `needShadow` parameter passed to the *form constructor* in this `CreateParams`. The `CreateParams` member is *executed before the first statement* in my custom form *constructor*, and I can't cache the `needShadow` value passed to the form constructor in a form field to use it later in `CreateParams`.

To solve the problem, I could turn this `needShadow` parameter into a *static property* of my form, set it before form creation and use this value in the overridden `CreateParams`. But obviously it is *not a good way* as my app can create several instances of this form, each with its own `needShadow` value.

Is there a neat solution to this problem in WinForms .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `CreateParams` will be called *several times*. First time call will be by `Form()` constructor without even `Handle` creation 
and that's why you can safely *ignore* it:

```
public partial class DropDownForm : Form { 
  private needShadow = false;

  public DropDownForm(bool needShadow) {
    this.needShadow = needShadow;

    // Actually, you should have needShadow set before this call
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

      if (needShadow)
        cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;

      return cp;
   }
 }
 ...
```